# How to make a function to work only on table row double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I added a jquery function to work on table row double click.For some reasons function working on double click.Am new with jquery and I am unable to find what I am missing.
I am using the **Jquery function:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        function addRowHandlers() {
            var table = document.getElementById("shTable");
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var currentRow = table.rows[i];
                var createClickHandler =
                    function (row) {
                        return function () {
                            var cell1 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                            //------------------------------------------
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "BankSettings.aspx/GetBranchDetails",
                                data: "{'BranchCode':'" + cell1.innerHTML + "'}",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: OnSuccess,
                                failure: function (response) {
                                    alert(response.d);
                                }

                            });
                            function OnSuccess(response) {
                                var data = response.d;                                                                       
                                var myData = JSON.parse(data);
                                $('#<%=txtbranchname.ClientID%>').val(myData.BranchName);
                                $('#<%=txtbranchcode.ClientID%>').val(myData.BrCode);
                                $('#<%=txtreglocal.ClientID%>').val(myData.RegLocal);
                                $('#<%=txtregstate.ClientID%>').val(myData.RegState);
                                $('#<%=txtregcentral.ClientID%>').val(myData.RegCentral);
                            }

                            ///-----------------------------------------
                        };
                    };

                    currentRow.dblclick= createClickHandler(currentRow);
                }
            }
        window.onload = addRowHandlers();
    });
```

Comment: Use this event -> [Jquery dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the *return value* of `createClickHandler` rather than *function reference* itself.

Replace

```
currentRow.dblclick= createClickHandler(currentRow);
```

with either ( [plain JS dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick) )

```
currentRow.dblclick = function ( event ){ createClickHandler( event.target ) };
```

**OR** using [jquery's dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

```
$( currentRow ).dblclick ( function( event ){ createClickHandler( event.target ) } );
```

Comment: thaks for helping hand . I tried both the statements ,but its not working

Comment: Its dynamic (created using C#) table so I don't have its HTML code .

Comment: Can you make a working snippet or fiddle with the code which is generated/rendered on browser?

Comment: ok let me add it with the question.!! Hope am not facing a browser compatibility issue..